# Any case studies using Bayesian Networks for system design trades?

Tags: data-mining, predictive-modeling, bayesian-networks

I am exploring using Bayesian Networks to identify the best parameters within a system design, to improve its performance. I'm trying to find any case studies where this has been used successfully or unsuccessfully.

As an example consider an automatic assisted anti-collision system on a car.  It could use some combination of ultrasonic, radar & IR seekers to sense and measure the closing speed with the car in front.  These all have different costs / reliabilities and perform differently in different weather conditions.  I am interested in understanding how effective Bayesian Networks can be in evaluating the trade space and identifying the best solutions to these types of problems.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you're searching for a case study. Learning from data is useful because you can learn both the conditional probability distributions (CPDs) and the structure of the network. The best resource I've read is a freely-available Microsoft tech report.

Have a look at the [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/heckerman/tutorial.pdf), maybe it can help you upto some extend. I'll suggest you to start with `Chapter 7` of it.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

There is a paper that was published at Systems&Cybernetics journal.

See how they use Bayesian Networks with sensor fusion:

[Active and dynamic information fusion for multi-sensor systems with dynamic bayesian networks](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1605392&tag=1).

Hope it helps.